# Why Eslint Plugins is found locally but I cannot build on the server?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, eslint

ESlint command on building server is failing with error:

```
ESLint couldn't find the plugin "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin".
```

Whereas, everything is working perfectly locally. There is no global eslint command on the server so it executes the Dev Dependency defined in Package.json

.eslintrc

```
"extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
```

Package.json

```
 "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.14.1",
 "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.13.0",
"eslint": "^7.18.0",
```

Comment: Have you run npm install on the server?

Comment: @Alex thanks for asking yes i did :(

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solve by adding

```
"root": true,
```

To **.eslintrc** file